# How to make a method overridable?

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I make a method "virtual" in typescript?

I am trying to do something like this:

```
export abstract class SuperClass {

    public virtual enable(enableComponents: boolean): void {

    }
}
```

Comment: What would this mean? You can already override any method. See e.g. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1524

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default typescript does not have any key word as **virtual, override**

**[Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)**

```
class A {

    public enable(enableComponents: boolean): void {

    }
}

class B extends A{

    public enable(enableComponents: boolean): void {

    }
}
```

Class that extends can also have the same function but the execution is based on the invoking object

Comment: yep, called shadowing

Comment: means? are you saying something?

Comment: adding that in javascript we're not overriding methods we're simply shadowing them due to prototypical inheritance.